# Sonar error - failed to unregister JDBC driver

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting the below error when trying to start the tomcat where SONAR is deployed. I have no clue what to be done. Please advice.

*SEVERE: The web application [/sonar] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.*

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the standalone mode. Indeed, the war mode has been removed since SonarQube 4.0. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Release+4.0+Upgrade+Notes